# Strange behavior of <a> tag

Tags: html

My code says

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>
```

But when it comes to the browser, it looks like the following and the link is not working.

```
<a&nbsp;href="http: www.example.com"="">example.com</a&nbsp;href="http:>
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: How is your code created?

Comment: Just hand coded HTML

Comment: Using what editor? Are you editing the file on the server directly, or uploading it?

Comment: Using Notepad++ and uploading it.

Comment: have you tried using regular Notepad ?

Comment: Yes, the same problem

Comment: do you the link for the this?

Comment: http://fragrantserenade.com/ FAQ section, any link to the website itself

Comment: If I add the tag at the beginning of a paragraph, then it's working well. But not at the end of the sentence!

Comment: sorry but I can't find a single link in this website that look like this, all your menu links are anchor names. so it seems fine to me.  I did a search on the source-code for &nbsp; and it came empty. where are you seeing this exactly?

Comment: @dippas: Search for the sentence: "Quiz questions will be available on the website" 

And there is a website linked. This is the one I'm talking about

Comment: One more thing, if I add a .(dot) at the end of the sentence after the website address, it works. But without the (dot), it's not working.

Comment: even without the (.)dot works perfect for me, using Firefox V32.0.3 view-source: `<p>Quiz questions will be available on the website <a href="http://FragrantSerenade.com">www.FragrantSerenade.com</a></p>` so what browser are you using? or are you using debug tool to view your code?

Comment: I'm using Chrom 37.0.2062.124 m

Comment: using same version as you of Chrome, the output is the same as Firefox 32.0.3  `<p>Quiz questions will be available on the website <a href="http://FragrantSerenade.com">www.FragrantSerenade.com</a></p>`

what I did was, using Chrome, in the address bar typed: *view-source:http://fragrantserenade.com/* and then searched for "Quiz questions will be available on the website" without quotes.

Comment: I took a look at your source code. you have invalid html, you are using `</br>` when should be `<br />`

Comment: It's strange! Anyway, I solved the problem by adding the dot for now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you copied or accidentally added a blank space in the html. Simply set your cursor in front of the a and hit backspace till you hit the < ;-) Rinse and repeat for the closing bracket.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to specify a doctype and a charset on your HTML file. Also remember to save your file as ".html" or ".htm".

Here is a small example of a basic HTML structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your document title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Your code goes here. 

    <a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've followed the same from the beginning itself. But no change!